# PHP with or logical and adding a class to the li global navigation

Tags: php, html, css

I'm in the process on covering the navigation bar on all the pages to a global navigation with the PHP.  I'm using PHP also to add a class and show the current page.

The challenge that I'm facing is the parent navigation selection.  It's underlined when it's on the child page and the sub-nav is also selected.  Such as I'm on the "History" page, child page to the "About Us" page.  Both are underlined.

The challenge that I'm facing is when I move over to the next page, "Service Areas" or any of it's children, the "About Us" nav selection is still underline.  I'm trying to use the || logic to prevent that from happening.

Below is the following code:

```
<li class="dropdown <?php if ($thisPage=='About Us'||'History'||'Mission Values'||'Process'||'Our People'||'Testimonials'||'Capstone Cares') echo 'active'; ?>">
```

Is there a way that I can deselect the parent nav when I'm under a different nav section?

Website is http://capstone.dgpehrson.com

Here is the rest of the code...

On individual pages I'm adding:

```
<?php $thisPage="About Us"; ?>
```

I'm changing the name according to the page.

Here is the Navigation code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown <?php if ($thisPage=='About Us' || 'History' || 'Mission Values' || 'Process' || 'Our People' || 'Testimonials' || 'Capstone Cares') echo 'active'; ?>">
      <a href="/about.php" class="dropdown-toggle">About Us<span class="caret"></span></a> <!-- Alink extentions that's been removed: data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" -->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li <?php if ($thisPage=="History") echo "class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="/about-history.php">History</a></li>
        <li <?php if ($thisPage=="Mission Values") echo "class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="/about-mission.php">Mission &amp; Values</a></li> 
        <li <?php if ($thisPage=="Process") echo "class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="/about-process.php">Process</a></li> 
        <li <?php if ($thisPage=="Our People") echo "class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="/about-ourpeople.php">Our People</a></li>
        <li <?php if ($thisPage=="Testimonials") echo "class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="/about-testimonials.php">Testimonials</a></li> 
        <li <?php if ($thisPage=="Capstone Cares") echo "class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="/about-capstone-cares.php">Capstone Cares</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown <?php if ($thisPage=='Service Areas'||'Apartments'||'Capital'||'Development Services'||'Manufactured Housing'||'Complimentary') echo 'active'; ?>">
      <a href="/service-areas.php">Service Areas<span class="caret"></span></a> <!-- Alink extentions that's been removed: data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" -->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li <?php if ($thisPage=="Apartments") echo "class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="/service-apartments.php">Apartments</a></li>
        <li <?php if ($thisPage=="Capital") echo "class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="/service-capital.php">Capital</a></li> 
        <li <?php if ($thisPage=="Development Services") echo "class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="/service-land.php">Developement Services</a></li>
        <li <?php if ($thisPage=="Manufactured Housing") echo "class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="/service-manufactured.php">Manufactured Housing</a></li> 
        <li <?php if ($thisPage=="Complimentary") echo "class=\"active\""; ?>><a href="/service-value.php">Complimentary Value Analysis</a></li> 
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="/offerings.php">Offerings<span class="caret"></span></a> <!-- Alink extentions that's been removed: data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" -->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/offerings-apartment.php">Apartment</a></li>
        <li><a href="/offerings-manufactured.php">Manufactured Housing</a></li> 
        <li><a href="/offerings-multi-family.php">Multi-family Land</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="/market-reports.php">Market Reports<span class="caret"></span></a> <!-- Alink extentions that's been removed: data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" -->
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="/market-florida.php">Florida</a></li>
        <li><a href="/market-kentucky.php">Kentucky</a></li> 
        <li><a href="/market-ncarolina.php">North Carolina</a></li>
        <li><a href="/market-scarolina.php">South Carolina</a></li>
        <li><a href="/market-tennessee.php">Tennessee</a></li>
        <li><a href="/market-virginia.php">Virginia</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/news.php">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/careers.php">Careers</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I'm on "About us" or "Service areas" page, both of them get the "active" class. You must have missed something in your condition, post the code for the whole navigation please.

Comment: @ROAL I added the rest of the code.  I'm still in the process of spreading it throughout the navigation, that's why you only see the PHP covering the first two areas until I can get this resolved.

Comment: I'm dumb. Only now I realized that, as Jason wrote in his answer, `$variable == 'Value 1' || 'Value 2'` is not correct syntax. This, to make it a bit clearer is basically `$variable == ('Value 1' || 'Value 2');`, where the part in parentheses gets evaluated first (as in math), and since `string OR string` will evaluate as `true`, all the conditions will be `true` in the end.

Comment: That makes two of us ;).  Thank you sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have the compare between each 'or'. The string is just evaluating to a true.

```
if ($thisPage=='About Us'||$thisPage=='History'||$thisPage=='Mission Values'||$thisPage=='Process'||$thisPage=='Our People'||$thisPage=='Testimonials'||$thisPage=='Capstone Cares') echo 'active';
```

Comment: Jason, this makes sense and works like a charm!  Thank you sir!